# How to replace some characters in UITextField by circle dots like in password textfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am implementing a feature related to finance and social security number, so I need to hide some numbers in credit card number or SSN textfield, currently I achieve this by using star characters (ex: SSN: 123456*****) but it would be nice if I could replace those stars by circle dots like in secured textfield (password textfield).

So anybody knows how to do this, please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Found a very good solution that using unicode character, and in my case is "\u25CF" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one...

```
NSString *string= @"7838473894653";

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(6, 4);
NSString *charToReplace=[string substringWithRange:range];
string= [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:charToReplace withString:@"●●●●"];
NSLog(@"string is %@",string);
```

**OR**

```
NSString *string= @"7838473894653";
int rangeLength=4;

NSString *replaceto=@"";

for (int i=0;i<rangeLength;i++) {
    replaceto=[replaceto stringByAppendingString:@"●"];
}

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(6, rangeLength);
NSString *charToReplace=[string substringWithRange:range];
string= [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:charToReplace withString:replaceto];
NSLog(@"string is %@",string);
```

outupt------------

string is 783847●●●●653

Comment: Thanks, actually I knew how to replace string, I just did know how to using the dot :)

Comment: Wouldn't this effect the actual string being entered ?

Comment: ● is a unicode character so it will not effect actual string , you can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/17425045/1305001

Answer (score 0):

you want to set the **secureTextEntry** property of that UITextField (UITextField has such a property because it conforms to the UITextInputTraits protocol) to YES:

```
textfield.secureTextEntry = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is hide just A PART of text, not all :). And it seems I found solution.