# Is it possible to insert Image between NSString?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uiimage

I am working on a product based application in which it shows product name with price increement or decreement.

As of now, according to my requirement I am inserting a UIImage as a subview to UILabel.But its everytime I need to calculate product name length on which I am defining x position of UIImage and adding it again and again.Product name is of variable size.

Not at all sometimes x position of image could not set properly so it overlaps text on UILabel.I stucked with this problem.

Below is my effort fired on such requirement.May be there should be another way to do such things but I don't know.Any other alternative I can apply?

```
int level=3;
NSString *product=@"Pea Price:";

UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 25)];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"]];

CGRect rect=[imgView frame];

UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 70, 200, 30)];
label.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

CGSize size=[product sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, 30) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
rect.origin.x=size.width-5;
[imgView setFrame:rect];

label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  (%i%%)",product,level];
[label addSubview:imgView];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: can you post screenshot of your requirement...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use like that

```
label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ⬆\uFE0E (%i%%)",product,level];
label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ⬇\uFE0E (%i%%)",product,level];
```

just copy and paste this arrow image to NSString.

Change foreColor of label will change the arrow color.

get Other Images to paste from here

**Arrows**  -- http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/miscellaneous_symbols_and_arrows.html

**Circular Digits** -- http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/enclosed_alphanumerics.html

**Images** -- http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/miscellaneous_symbols.html

**Smiles** -- http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/emoticons.html

**Miscallaneous** -- http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/miscellaneous-symbols-and-pictographs.html

Comment: FYI, there's a [character viewer embedded right into MacOS](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH6597) that's more than handy, with _all_ the Unicode characters.

Comment: I will check @Cyrille thnks

Comment: how to change image color? i have to add white arrow frame

Answer (score 1):

You could use Unicode characters for arrows (⬈ and ⬊) with NSAttributedStrings for colors, or even Emojis : ↗ and ↘ (view this page in the Simulator to see them).

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to achieve this is to use a `UIWebView` and insert your image as an HTML tag. But performance-wise, it's not great.

Comment: I am using it in tableViewCell